# How to force files to be served as html

Tags: apache

I've got HTML files stored with no extension (terribly, its a bad idea, but i must it), and apache is serving them as plain text?

How to configure APACHE to serve them as html?

Comment: You can add .html to all of them: `find . -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.html \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Define defaultType

[DefaultType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#defaulttype) specifies what mime type to use as the default (unknown extensions, or as is the case here, no extension).

So e.g. either modify the apache config to specify default type for the given directory:

```
<Directory /path/to/public_html/test/local>
    # Force html
    DefaultType text/html
</Directory>
```

Or create a `.htaccess` file in `public_html/test/local` to do the same:

```
# Force html
DefaultType text/html
```